# asp.net ajax success handler is working but throw System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i want to connect to mssql db using ajax
ajax is working because success handler is working
but result data have System.InvalidOperationException
and messagebox in readdata function is not working....
query has not problem...

how can i fix it?

```
   // .aspx.cs
   public string readData(String location)
{
    string lct = location;
    String sql = "select * from eom_eq_issue where issue_id = '5274'";
    //String sql = "SELECT * FROM EQ_LOCATION_TEST WHERE LCT_KEY =" + lct;
    String result = string.Empty;

    this.openDB();
    MessageBox.Show("!!!!");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = objCon;
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        result = dr["eq_cd"].ToString();
        dr.Close();
    }
    //dr.Close();

    return result;
}


   //.js
   clickEvent: function (location) {

    var url = "TotalView.aspx/readData"
    var DATA = { location: location };

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        data: DATA,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        //datatype: "xml",
        success: function (result) {
            gw_job_process.successFN(result, location);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("error"+e.responseText);
        }
    }).fail(function($xhr){
        alert("fail");
    });

}
```

Comment: First off, `readData` needs to be a static `[WebMethod]`

Comment: yes i did it and added 'using System.Web.Services;'